Questions about changing frame in QM and rotating wave approximation (1 Viewer)
I have a 3 level system with energies $E_0$, $E_1$ and $E_2$ and 2 time varying electric fields, the first one connects $E_0$ and $E_1$ while the second one connects $E_0$ and $E_2$ with Rabi frequencies $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ and the frequencies of the electric fields are $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ such that $|E_0-E_1-\omega_1|\ll|E_0-E_1|$ and $|E_0-E_2-\omega_2|\ll|E_0-E_2|$. So my Hamiltonian looks like:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
E_0                    & \Omega_1\cos\omega_1 t & \Omega_2\cos\omega_2 t\\
\Omega_1\cos\omega_1 t & E_1                    & 0\\
\Omega_2\cos\omega_2 t & 0                      & E_2
\end  {pmatrix}
$$
If I had only $E_0$, $E_1$, I would use this matrix:
$$U = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & e^{i\omega_1 t}
\end  {pmatrix}
$$
to go in a frame rotating with the electric field and remove all the explicit time dependence from the problem. But I am not sure what to do for a 3 level system (i.e. can I remove all the time dependence?). In principle I can use this for a 3 level system:
$$U = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0               & 0\\
0 & e^{i\omega_1 t} & 0\\
0 & 0               & e^{i\omega_2 t}
\end  {pmatrix}
$$
which would give a time-independent Hamitlonian (and that is a valid unitary transformation), but I am not sure this is ok physically. Basically, if I use this, the 2 different excited states seem to be in different rotating frames, which is confusing to me. What is the right way to proceed? Can I actually go to a time independent frame that makes physical sense?
